# Target Multiple Sprites Based on their Name?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

The problem with this code is that it's only targeting 1 SKNode named "coin", I want to target all SKNodes named "coin". I'm not sure how to do this...

Heres what I have:

```
func killCoins(){
    let skcoin: SKNode = self.childNodeWithName("coin")!
    // Looks for a SKNode named "coin".
    let coinsprite: SKSpriteNode = (skcoin as? SKSpriteNode)!
    // Converts the SKNode into a SKSpriteNode
    coinsprite.removeFromParent()
    // Kills Sprite
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove multiple `SKSpriteNode`s, loop through all of the children and remove those `SKSpriteNode`s with the name `"coin"`.

```
func killCoins() {
    for child in self.children where child is SKSpriteNode {
        if child.name == "coin" {
            child.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

You can look for all the children `SKSpriteNode(s)` having `coin` as name. The following code is totally Functiona Programming oriented

```
func killCoins() {
    self
        .children
        .filter { $0 is SKSpriteNode && $0.name == "coin" }
        .forEach { $0.removeFromParent() }
}
```

The time of this operation is `O(n)` where `n` is the total number of children of the current node/scene.
We can do better.

### Solution 2

Just create a special node that will be the parent of all the coins

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let coins = SKNode()
    coins.name = "coins"
    self.addChild(coins)

    let coin0 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin")
    coins.addChild(coin0)

    let coin1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin")
    coins.addChild(coin1)
}
```

Now the `killCoins` becomes

```
func killCoins() {
    self.childNodeWithName("coins")?.removeAllChildren()
}
```

The time complexity of this operation is `O(m)` where `m` is the number of the coins.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to vacawama's answer, you can use [enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:) for [more advanced searches](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013023-CH1-SW74):

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("coin") {
    node, stop in 
    // do something with node or stop
}
```

From the docs:

> This method enumerates the child array in order, searching for nodes
>   whose names match the search parameter. The block is called once for
>   each node that matches the name parameter.